# Run javascript function with setInterval

Tags: javascript, php

I'm attempting to run a javascript function to rotate between Divs every 1500ms (1.5s)

Currently my script looks like:

```
<?php 
  $rowCount = 3;
  $prefix = 'ITS_';
?>
var step = 1;
var stepmax = <?php echo $rowCount; ?>;
var prefix = <?php echo $prefix; ?>;
var myRotator = setInterval(rotator, 1500);

function rotator() {
    if (step > stepmax) step = 1;
    var stepname = prefix + String(step);
    openTab(event, stepname);
    step++;
}
```

However no rotation is occuring, I know the openTab function is good, I can run it on a button press without issue.

Page is in PHP 5.6 running in Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Use Case (restated):
Once the page loads run the openTab function every 1.5s incrementing the stepname up by 1 until it reaches the stepmax then reset to 1 and repeat indefinitely.

Comment: Try using `setinterval()` like this `setInterval(function(){ rotator(); }, 1500);`

Comment: @JeffP. - I did try that, the function is running, it seems to not be incrementing, it keeps running openTab(event, ITS_1) it seems (if I manually change to ITS_2 it switches back at 1.5s exactly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works... if you do something like this and it keeps failing, it means there is a problem with your rotate function, not with the interval...

```js
var step = 1;
var stepmax = 5;
var prefix = "prefix_";
var myFunc= function(){
  console.log("prefix_"+step);
  if(step<stepmax)
  step++;
  else
  step=1
  
}
var myRotator = setInterval(myFunc, 1500);
```